# Type mismatch for generic Integral in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, encoding, type-conversion

I am trying to code a decoder for [Base64 Variable Length Quanties](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) in  Scala.

(Base64 VLQ encodes a sequences of signed integers. The encoding has no restrictions on the range of integers encoded.)

For my current use case, I kow that `Seq[Int]` will suffice. Of course, I'd like to make it so I can decode to `Seq[Long]`, or `Seq[BigInteger]`, or even something like `Seq[Short]`.

The algorithm is exactly the same, just with different types.

Generics to the rescue! (Or so I thought.)

---

```
object Base64Vlq {
  val continuationMask = (1 << 5).toByte
  val signMask = 1.toByte

  def decode[T <: Integral[T]](bytes: Seq[Byte]): Seq[T] = {
    val result = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[T]()
    bytes.foldLeft((0, 0)) { (arg, byte) =>
      val (value, n) = arg
      if((byte & continuationMask) == 0) {
        val newValue = value + (byte / 2 & ~continuationMask) << 5 * n
        result += (if((byte & signMask) == 0) { newValue } else { -newValue })
        (0, 0)
      } else {
        (value + (byte & ~continuationMask).toInt << 5 * n, n + 1)
      }
    }
    result
  }
}
```

This has a compile error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : newValue.type (with underlying type Int)
required: T
       result += (if((byte & signMask) == 0) { newValue } else { -newValue })
```

I can see the problem: `0`, `value`, and `newValue` are all of type `Int`.

What can I do to fix this?

---

FYI, this is how I would do the same thing in C++, with only a couple more lines of code.

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> decode(std::vector<char> bytes) {
    char continuationMask = 1 << 5;
    char signMask = 1;
    vector<T> result;
    int n(0);
    T value(0);
    for(auto it = bytes.begin(); it != bytes.end(); it++) {
        if(*it & continuationMask) {
            value += (*it & ~continuationMask) << 5 * n;
            n++;
        } else {
            value += (*it / 2 & ~continuationMask) << 5 * n;
            result.push_back(*it & signMask ? -value : value);
            value = 0;
            n = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

P.S. As a side note, if anyone knows of a Java/Scala based Base64 VLQ implementation in public Maven/Ivy repos, even if it's not generic, I'd appreciate knowing it.

Comment: Any "generic" solution in Scala will be slow. You may try to use specialization to get better performance, but I'm not sure how far that will get you. If you need speed, and this looks like it needs, stay non-generic.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, yes, Java generics are slow. Alexey's solution, even with specialization, there would still be a performance hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bound `T <: Integral[T]` says `T` must be a *subtype* of `Integral[T]`, which is wrong; you need a *context bound* `T: Integral` instead or (better for this case) an implicit parameter (actually, a context bound compiles to an implicit parameter, the only difference is that you can't give it a name).

Something like this (not tested, just checked that it compiles):

```
object Base64Vlq {
  val continuationMask = (1 << 5).toByte
  val signMask = 1.toByte

  def decode[T](bytes: Seq[Byte])(implicit ev: Integral[T]): Seq[T] = {
    val result = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[T]()
    val tZero = ev.zero
    bytes.foldLeft((tZero, 0)) { (arg, byte) =>
      val (value, n) = arg
      if((byte & continuationMask) == 0) {
        val newValue = ev.plus(value, ev.fromInt((byte / 2 & ~continuationMask) << 5 * n))
        result += (if((byte & signMask) == 0) { newValue } else { ev.negate(newValue) })
        (tZero, 0)
      } else {
        (ev.plus(value, ev.fromInt((byte & ~continuationMask).toInt << 5 * n)), n + 1)
      }
    }
    result
  }
}
```

To use, you'll have to say what type you want to get out:

EDIT: I didn't see that in your C++ code `n` was `T` and assumed it was an `Int`.

Answers to the comment:

1. That's just how types like `Integral` work: they are Scala's version of [type classes](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html). If you want to introduce new operations on existing types, you obviously can't add new supertypes to them, so instead implicit instances for `Integral[Int]`, `Integral[BigInt]` and so on are created.
2. The compiler doesn't know what type to use for `T` and you need to tell it: e.g. `Base64Vlq.decode[Int](Seq[Byte]())` or `Base64Vlq.decode[BigInt](Seq[Byte]())`.

Comment: Can you (1) elaborate why it there has to be an instance of `Integral[T]`, and (2) how to use this? `Base64Vlq.decode(Seq[Byte]())` gives `error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both object BigIntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type object scala.math.Numeric.BigIntIsIntegral
 and object IntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type object scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral
 match expected type Integral[T]`.

Comment: Oh duh...#2 should have been obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there's an import you can use to avoid the awkward syntax of `Integral` type class and use normal infix math operators (while still using the type class to implement them).

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't solve your issue, but hopefully it helps you to write a generic solution. Take a look at operations provided by [Integral](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Integral) and [IntegralOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Integral%24IntegralOps). The problem is with bit operations. If you choose to go this way, you would have to rewrite them using operations supported by Integral and IntegralOps. Good luck.

```
object Base64Vlq {
  val continuationMask = (1 << 5).toByte
  val signMask = 1.toByte

  def decode[T](bytes: Seq[Byte])(implicit integral: Integral[T]): Seq[T] = {
    import integral._

    val result = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[T]()
    bytes.foldLeft((integral.zero, integral.zero)) { (arg, byte) =>
      val (value, n) = arg
      if((byte & continuationMask) == integral.zero) {
        // Just a meaningless example calculation:
        result += integral.fromInt(2) + (value * n)

        (integral.zero, integral.zero)
      } else {
        // Just a meaningless example calculation:
        (value + integral.fromInt(3) * n, n + integral.fromInt(1))
      }
    }
    result
  }
}
```